# How to utilize old classes with the underlines in Zend Framework 2

Tags: zend-framework2

I need to autoload old style classes in ZF2. The classes are located in vendor directory.

What is the best way to this?

Comment: with the underlines "_"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ZF's [StandardAutoloader](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/modules/zend.loader.standard-autoloader.html#zend-loader-standard-autoloader) class provides a fallback autoloading mechanism for non-namespaced classes. Try to set `fallback_autoloader` key to `true` in your Application module's getAutoloaderConfig() method something like below:

```
public function getAutoloaderConfig()
{
    return array(
        'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => array(
            'namespaces' => array(
                __NAMESPACE__ => __DIR__ . '/src',
                'Ancientlib'  => '/path/to/ancient/library'
            ),
            'fallback_autoloader' => true,
        )
    );
}
```

Also there is an article by Rob Allen about this subject.

Provides more details about this subject: [Using Zend\Loader\Autoloader](http://akrabat.com/zend-framework-2/using-zendloaderautoloader/)